# Saving/Updating a value

Tags: python

I don't know how to say this but I need to save a value inside a function, for example a number. Then incrementing by 1 each time it executes. Say it is Operation ID and it is n° 200. It executes five times and it prints 201, 202, 203, 204 and 205. What I need is that 205 is automatically set to next value in case of a future execution of the function.
Let me try to elaborate:

```
idOperacion = 200  # ID

for i in range(len(trx.index)): # HAS 5 ITEMS
     idOperacion = idOperacion + 1
```

And then it prints `201, 202, 203, 204 and 205`

I want that 205 to be `idOperacion` the mext time I execute the script with out changing it by hand.

Comment: Just use a global variable? I don't understand why there is difficulty. If you have a specific problem related to a function, please show code *that involves a function*.

Comment: you need to store your value somewhere in order to make it begin from the last updated id value for the next execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save you variable within a external file.
This is a lot of ways to save and load data.

Here is a mehtod that fulfill your needs

- loading

```py
with open('idOperacion') as f:
    idOperacion = int(f.read())
```

- saving

```py
with open('idOperacion', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(idOperacion))
```

Comment: Had to arrange some lines but it sure worked. Thank you!!!